# Accidentally removed my app keystore file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an application on Google Play, and I want to release an update but I accidentally clicked the - button on the Signing Identity tab in the Distribute manager and now I cannot find the old keystore file, even not in the trash. Is this file totally lost?

Comment: Please Remember that if a question answers your question to mark it as an Answer for future users facing the error otherwise let us know if a answer doesn't suite the use case and we can work on it further

Answer (score 2):

For Windows:

Locate the Xamarin debug.keystore file used to sign the app. By default, the keystore used to sign debug versions of a Xamarin.Android application can be found in the following location:

C: \ Users \ USERNAME \ AppData \ Local \ Xamarin \ Mono for Android \ debug.keystore

Information about a key store is obtained by running the command keytool.exefrom the JDK. This tool is typically located in the following location:

C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Java \ jdk VERSION \ bin \ keytool.exe

Add the directory containing keytool.exe to the environment variable. Open a command prompt and run using the following command:

```
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

When run, keytool.exe should return the following text. The MD5: and SHA1: labels identify the respective signatures:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Aug 19, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 53f3b126
Valid from: Tue Aug 19 13:18:46 PDT 2014 until: Sun Nov 15 12:18:46 PST 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  27:78:7C:31:64:C2:79:C6:ED:E5:80:51:33:9C:03:57
         SHA1: 00:E5:8B:DA:29:49:9D:FC:1D:DA:E7:EE:EE:1A:8A:C7:85:E7:31:23
         SHA256: 21:0D:73:90:1D:D6:3D:AB:4C:80:4E:C4:A9:CB:97:FF:34:DD:B4:42:FC:
08:13:E0:49:51:65:A6:7C:7C:90:45
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
```

The Documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/keystore-signature?tabs=windows): Mention the same Steps for Mac if u want to have a read through that, Otherwise From my Knowledge if you have completely lost the Upload Key, You have to contact the app store to generate you a new one.